# How can I move a label under a text box?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Good evening everyone, I am creating a form in an asp.net core solution and I have a problem with my ccs.

When I press the send button and I have empty inputs, it validates and sends an error message; the problem is when this action is executed, the size of the inputs changes.
How can I move these labels under my text boxes?

```
<label asp-for="CxP_NroControl" class="control-label"></label>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-paragraph"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input asp-for="CxP_NroControl" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="CxP_NroControl" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<label asp-for="CxP_NroFactura" class="control-label"></label>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-paragraph"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input asp-for="CxP_NroFactura" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="CxP_NroFactura" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use `display:block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Following CSS will give you desire output.

```
span.text-danger {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Is there really a CSS property called `Display`?

Comment: he meant, D vs d

Comment: Ohhh Man capital 'D' doesn't harm. i agree use lowercase is better its work doesn't matter.